# Where pointers without initialisation points?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *b;
    int *a;
    a[1] = 99;
    printf("%p", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code fails with segfault:
**Process finished with exit code 11**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //int *b;
    int *a;
    a[1] = 99;
    printf("%p", a);
    return 0;
}
```

And this code prints and address of pointer?
**0x7fff58162a40**
How a[1] = 99 works, if i haven't initialised pointer a? 
compiling with gcc on mac os Sierra, if this matters.

Comment: Neither of these _work_. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Vladimir -- `a` is simply a pointer to `int` here; you need to allocate some memory for `a` to point to if you want to store an `int` value someplace.

Comment: Could you try assigning a value to a[0]. Because a is the adress of 0. element not 1. element.

Comment: @TalipTolgaSarı -- that would also be undefined behavior since `a` has not been initialized nor assigned any value; `a` has _indeterminate value_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing uninitialized variables and/or writing to an object/array for which you did not request memory is undefined behaviour. "Undefined" means that everything can happen, even that the program seems to "work" as you intended.

Actually both programs do both; if one of them "works" then it is some kind of luck (good or bad, you may decide).